# Python key error JSON

Tags: python, json, api, key, datumbox

I am trying to do the twitter sentiment analysis feature from the Datumbox API and keep having an issue. My function to make a call the API looks like this:

```
def call(text):
    api_key = '<my_api_key>'
    base_url = "http://api.datumbox.com/1.0/TwitterSentimentAnalysis.json?"
    response = requests.get(base_url+'api_key='+api_key+'&'+'text='+text)
    data = response.json()
    result = data['output']['result']
    return result
```

Most times this function works. However, I keep getting KeyError: 'result' as the error when I try and run the function after a couple hundred times. The following is the documentation for the API:

```
JSON Response:
{
 "output": {
 "status": 1,
 "result": "positive"
 }
}
```

JSON “result” value: In this function the possible values of the above JSON result field are:
"positive", "negative" or "neutral"

Does anyone know what could possibly be wrong with my function?

Comment: That may be what the documentation says, but what is the *actual* value of data in your script?

Comment: http://www.datumbox.com/files/API-Documentation-1.0v.pdf   -- Here is the link the documentation. I want my function to take a string and return either 'positive' 'negative' or 'neutral'

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for the API:

> If an error occurs while executing your call, our API will return a status of 0.  In that case it
>   results also the error code and the error message. Here is how an Error Reply looks like:
>
> ```
> {
>   "output": {
>     "status": 0,
>     "error": {
>       "ErrorCode": 6,
>       "ErrorMessage": "Invalid Account"
>     }
> }
> ```

You want to *first* check if `status` is set to `1` before trying to access the `result` key, because if `status` is set to `0` there won't be such a key:

```
data = response.json()
if data['output']['status']:
    return data['output']['result']
else:
    raise SomeException(
        'Failed to get a result, error {0[ErrorCode]}, {0[ErrorMessage]!r}'.format(
            data['output']['error']))
```